# mysql-connector can't release global read lock

Tags: jboss, jboss-tools

debezium-connector-mysql,debezium-core and debezium-embedded.
I use these debezium plugin in my java app.
Problem:
Method throws StopConnectorException then can't released "global read lock"

Comment: Can you share the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, there isn't stacktrace ! Blocking in:"Step 2: flush and obtain global read lock to prevent writes to database" when I start another mysql connector engine,  THX

Answer (score 0):

If using a hosted option that does not allow a global read lock, table-level locks are used to create the consistent snapshot. In this case, you need to also grant LOCK TABLES permissions to the user that you create.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html